# TextView animation expand only one line

Tags: android, animation, textview

I need to animate a TextView when i click a button. The height of the TextView is wrap_content. This TextView is inside a RecyclerView row and i need to expand it from visibility gone to his real height with content. I used ValueAnimator.

```
private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end) {
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = tvAdditional.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            tvAdditional.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}

private void expand(View v) {
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, v.getMeasuredHeight());
    mAnimator.start();
}

private void collapse(final View v) {
    int finalHeight = v.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}
```

In debug i noticed that when i use `getMeasuredHeight()` method on view in `expand`, the value is always 76, also if i added items with more than one row.

P.s. i call `expand` and `collapse` inside the click listener of the row.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I changed my `expand` method adding a listener in which i set the height to wrap_content at the end of the animation:

```
private void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, targetHeight);
    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    mAnimator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have the Visibility as GONE, you cannot know it's measured height until it's actually drawn. In order to have that, you need to have GlobalLayoutListener on that TextView, so you can get it's measured height when it's drawn.

In your expand method, I see that you set the Visibility to Visible and then try to measure it, which won't be drawn immediately, so you cannot get the height.

So what you can do to get the actual height of the TextView if it's visibility is initially gone, first you should change the initial visibility to VISIBLE, second, set a Global Layout Listener and as third step, store the TextView's height in a global value after you measure it, and as the last step, you can set the Visibility of TextView as GONE.

This process is normally really quick, so you won't be able to see the TextView's visibility changing from VISIBLE to GONE with your eyes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now a question came to my mind: if i use this method, how can i save in a global variable the height of the row that i clicked? I mean according to the fact that i need to do the process GONE - VISIBLE - GONE

Comment: so two questions, 1-) is your View (that you clicked to expand/collapse) initially GONE ? Do you first click to expand it ? 2-) Are they all have the same height in the RecyclerView row ? If you can also attach a ScreenShot that would help me to understand it clearly.

Comment: My view is initially gone, i need to click to expand/collapse them and they haven't the same height. I can attach a screen now

Comment: So I could see, your "Quantity" text and the one you want to expand has same height. Why don't you use the height of Visible Text View ?

Comment: I had a similar feature in one of my apps, and I ended up using [this](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/wiki/ExpandableListItemAdapter) library. It handles it in a quite nice way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79370/discussion-between-fondesa-and-osayilgan).